# Unexpected CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE from cuLaunchKernel()

Tags: cuda, cuda-driver

I'm trying to launch a kernel using the CUDA driver API. Specifically I'm calling

```
CUresult CUDAAPI cuLaunchKernel(
    CUfunction f,
    unsigned int gridDimX,  unsigned int gridDimY,  unsigned int gridDimZ,
    unsigned int blockDimX, unsigned int blockDimY, unsigned int blockDimZ,
    unsigned int sharedMemBytes,
    CUstream hStream,
    void **kernelParams,
    void **extra);
```

I'm only using `kernelParams`, and passing `nullptr` for `extra`. Now, for one of my kernels, I get `CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE`.

The documentation [says](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__EXEC.html):

> The error `CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE` will be returned if kernel parameters are specified with both `kernelParams` and `extra` (i.e. both `kernelParams` and `extra` are non-`NULL`).

well, I'm not doing that, and am still getting `CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE`. To be extra-safe, I synch'ed the stream right before launching the kernel - but to no avail.

What are the other reasons for getting `CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE` when trying to launch?

Comment: Your textualist reading of selected parts of the documentation is getting in the way again. That isn't the only condition which can return CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE. Any incorrect arguments other than the function itself will also produce the same error

Comment: @talonmies: Including the grid dims and block dims? excessive shared memory? invalid stream handle?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you can get a `CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE` error in multiple cases involving issues with your `kernelParams` and/or `extras` arguments:

1. Both `kernelParams` and `extras` are null, but the kernel takes parameters.
2. Both `kernelParams` and `extras` are non-null (this is what's officially documented)
3. The number of elements in `kernelParams` before the terminating `nullptr` value doesn't match the number of kernel parameters.

and this is not an exhaustive list. Probably misusing `extras` can cause this too.